# Adding selectors into dynamically generated <li > element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically generate html content. However it seem like whenever I add tags or selectors to the `li` element, the code malfunctions

[Correct behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/1/)

[Incorrect behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/672/)

```
$('#btnName').click(function(){
    var text = $('#inputName').val() + '<button>x</button>';
    if(text.length){
        $('<li name="somename" id="someid"/>', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.justList') // adding name tag and id selector cause error
    }
});

$('ul').on('click','button' , function(el){
    $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

Comment: try this `$('<li />', {html: text}).attr('name','somename').attr('class','someclass').appendTo('ul.justList')` here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/673/

Comment: The "name" attribute is not valid for `<li>` elements, and you shouldn't give all the `<li>` elements you add the same id.

Comment: @Sushil why use the attr object `{}` then add more attributes with `.attr()`?

Comment: @Popnoodles he needs to add additional attributes to the li element hence i used `.attr()`

Comment: @Sushil the point is that you can do that in the second parameter where the original fiddle is setting the "html" property

Comment: yeah i get your point @Pointy. you're right

Comment: I didn't see that properly @Popnoodles. the second parameter is better instead of using the `.attr()`

Comment: FYI: Your `if` statement doesn't make a lot of sense. You are concatenating a hard-coded string and checking the length of the returned string! The length is always more than 0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/674/)**

Use the second parameter to set the other attributes rather than write them out in the tag. Also, you don't need to self-close the tag.

```
$('#btnName').click(function(){
    var text = $('#inputName').val() + '<button>x</button>';
    if(text.length){
        $('<li>', {
            html: text,
            name: 'somename',
            id: 'someid' + $('.justList li').length // for the sake of unique ids in the example
        }).appendTo('ul.justList')
    }
});
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not an attribute object. jQuery iterates through the object, if `key` is a jQuery method, it calls the corresponding method using the set value otherwise it uses the `attr` method for adding an attribute.